# Launched app moves to background by itself

Tags: android, appium

I have observed a strange behavior in Appium. The apps that I launch with the following piece of code eventually move to background automatically.

```
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

I have observed with 2 apps and only when doing this via code. When manually opened, these apps run normally. Is this normal? How can I keep the launched apps opened?
P.S.: I am using Android Emulator for my testing.

Comment: can you show all capabilities ? is it going in background before test case execution or after test case execution ? is your test case working or not.

Comment: capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 5X");<br/>
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");<br/>
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "<packageName>");<br/>
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","<activityName>");<br/>
capabilities.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "Portrait");<br/>
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");<br/>
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());<br/>
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);<br/>
App launches and moves to background.